# producer-consumer stack behavior instead of queue

Tags: c, producer-consumer

I have coded a solution to the standard producer-consumer problem using a buffer of size 5 and pthreads with an empty and full semaphore and mutex lock.  I thought everything was working as expected but just noticed I am getting Stack behavior(LIFO) rather than the expected queue(FIFO) behavior.  I have searched but couldn't find any similar issues since I am producing and consuming as expected other than the order.

This is a homework assignment so I am not really looking for code I am just wondering where to look for the error or know why the behavior may be different than expected.

```
struct data
{
pthread_mutex_t mutex;  
sem_t full;             
sem_t empty;
};

int bufferCount;        

buffer_item buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
pthread_t thread;

int insert_item(buffer_item item)
{
  if (bufferCount < BUFFER_SIZE)
  {
    buffer[bufferCount] = item;
    ++bufferCount;
    return 0;
  }
  else
    return -1; //insert failed 
}

int remove_item(buffer_item *item)
{
  if (bufferCount > 0) 
  {
    *item = buffer[bufferCount - 1];
    --bufferCount;
    return 0;
  }
  else
    return -1; //error failed to remove

}

void Initialize (void *param)
{
  struct data *locks = param;

  pthread_mutex_init(&(locks->mutex), NULL);
  sem_init(&(locks->full), 0, 0);
  sem_init(&(locks->empty), 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
  bufferCount = 0;

}

void *producer (void *param)
{
  struct data *locks = param;
  do
  {
    sleep(rand()%5 + 1); //sleep for between 1 and 5 seconds
    buffer_item num = rand();
    sem_wait(&(locks->empty));
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(locks->mutex));
    if (insert_item(num))
    {
      printf("Insert in producer failed\n");
      exit(1);
    }
    else
      printf("Producer produced %d\n", num);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(locks->mutex));
    sem_post(&(locks->full));
  }while(1);
}


void *consumer (void *param)
{
  struct data *locks = param;
  do
  {
    sleep(rand()%5 + 1); //sleep for between 1 and 5 seconds
    buffer_item num;
    sem_wait(&(locks->full));
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(locks->mutex));
    if (remove_item(&num))
    {
      printf("Remove in consumer failed\n");
      exit(1);
    }
    else
      printf("Consumer consumed %d\n", num);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(locks->mutex));
    sem_post(&(locks->empty));
  }while(1);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (argc != 4)
  {
    printf("Incorrect number of arguments should be 4\n");
    exit (1);
  }
  int sleepTime = atoi(argv[1]);  
  int producerThreads = atoi(argv[2]);
  int consumerThreads = atoi(argv[3]);
  struct data *locks = (struct data *) malloc(sizeof(struct data));
  Initialize(locks);

  for (int i =0; i < producerThreads; ++i)
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, producer, locks);

  for(int i = 0; i < consumerThreads; ++i)
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, consumer, locks);

  sleep(sleepTime); 
  free (locks);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: the error is in line 42

Comment: Funny.....I am sure I can post the code and hundreds of people can make it better and fix it but I want to learn from it.  So in general in a producer consumer problem what could impact the order the consumer removes from the buffer.

Comment: that do you expect from us? if you coded a LIFO instead of FIFO than the obvious guess is that you your consumers consume from the wrong end of your container. but that is so obvious that you surely checked this by yourself

Comment: The reason you should post your code is so we can see and understand what you did. This is often essential in providing a helpful answer. If you only want tips or pointers and no complete code snippets that fix your problem, you can just say so in the question like you did.

Comment: Fair enough....edited and posted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "error" lies here : `*item = buffer[bufferCount - 1];`

When you remove an item, you popped the furthest in the array , which is also the last inserted (thus LIFO behaviour). You need to pop the first one (and memcpy/index-keeping to shift the start of the buffer).

What you do :

```
begin         <-end  
-------------------
| | | | | | | | |x|
-------------------
                 |
                 -> *item
```

What you want to do :

```
begin->         end  
-------------------
|x| | | | | | | | |
-------------------
 |
 -> *item
```

PS : there are performance penalty to memcpy the buffer to realign the beginning of the data array, which is why [circular buffers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) are often used.

Comment: Thanks....figured it was something I was overlooking was just sick of staring at the code and seeing nothing different that was causing the problem.